# Node.js and Socket.io moving from local development server to live server, not connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have built a private chat system using Node.js and Socket.io on my local development server, and it is working fine, sends messages, updates the database whenever the client accepts the message event.  However, the past two days I have been trying to push this to my live Rackspace server.   I have been chatting with Rackspace and they have spun up my node server, I have a console.log that prints "Server listening on port: xxxx".  I will post my node.js server code as well as some of my client code.  I am just not sure what is going wrong as it worked fine on my local development.  Chrome console is giving me a error of 'io is not defined' which it is, which is making me think that it is not loading the socket.io/socket.io.js from the node server.  However, I thought that it would give me an error on the GET request.

I am new to Node.js and Socket.io and do not understand everything about it.  I am trying to use this on vhost host, could this cause a problem?

```
var express = require('express');
app = require('http').createServer(handler),
//server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io')(app);
fs = require('fs');

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server listening on: 3000");
});

var clients = {};

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}

//app.get('/', function(req, res){
//  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
//});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("Connected!");
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });

    socket.on('add-user', function(data){
        clients[data.username] = {"socket" : socket.id};
        console.log(data.username+' / '+clients[data.username].socket);    
    });

    socket.on('private-message', function(data){
        console.log("Sending: " + data.content + " to " + data.username);
        if (clients[data.username]){
            io.sockets.connected[clients[data.username].socket].emit("add-  message", data);
        } else {
           console.log("User does not exist: " + data.username); 
        }
  });

//Removing the socket on disconnect
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    for(var name in clients) {
        if(clients[name].socket === socket.id) {
            delete clients[name];
            break;
        }
    }   
  });

});
```

Client Code:

```
var socket = io;
socket.connect('x.x.x.x:3000');
var viewingUser = $('#viewingUserID').val();
socket.on("news", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

socket.emit("add-user", {"username" : viewingUser });

So I replaced "<script type="text/javascript" src="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js">"  with "<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>"
```

This is the error:

```
GET http://23.253.247.166:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1439565622045-29 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: So I replaced "<script type="text/javascript" src="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js">"  with "<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>"

Answer (score 0):

Your server does not have a request handler for the socket.io javascript file.

You browse to your website and your server gets a request, you handle it by sending the index.html file.

When the index.html file is being processed by the browser, it will find the socket.io script tag and make a request to the server for it, but you only respond to requests by sending the index.html file.

Either:

- Try replacing the script tag src with a CDN version of socket.io (client version).

or

- Add a request handler to send the javascript file when requested

If you have to serve static content (like webpages / javascript / css / images / ...) express makes it very easy:

`app.use(express.static('public'));` Where `public` would be the folder of your static assets.

Server code:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

// Socket stuff goes here. but try this for a start
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Server listening on:3000');
});
```

Comment: Also, I just noticed, shouldn't it be: `var socket = io();` in the client side script?